# Can't send JSON to server, but ajax call is working

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have the following code:

serverside.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.post('/LEDon', function(req, res) {
    var obj = res;
    console.log('LEDon button pressed!');
    // Run your LED toggling code here
});
app.listen(1337);
```

clientside.js:

```
$('#ledon-button').click(function() {
    var test = "123";
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:1337/LEDon',
        data: JSON.stringify(test),
        contentType: 'application/json'
    });
});
```

view.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id='ledon-button'>LED on</button> 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">
    </script> 
    <script src='clientside.js'>
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Nothing happens when I click the button. But if I remove some lines from clientside.js it works:

```
$('#ledon-button').click(function() {
    var test = "123";
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:1337/LEDon',
    });
});
```

But this way no JSON-file is being sent. I tried looking at tutorials but found nothing. What am I missing?

Comment: why is your JSON just a string? don't you want `var test = { foo : "123" }`

Comment: For testing purposes. I used object before, but wanted to see if there was something wrong with that or the syntax

Comment: Try sending `{ test : "123" }` and see what you get.

Comment: Well you have a trailing comma, but that should not be an issue. Do you see the Ajax call in the console? You do not have an error handler or success callbacks so not sure how you are debugging it working.

Comment: nurdyguy: no difference

Comment: epascarello: trailing comma was not the issue. 

i do not see the call in the console no

Comment: You need to send an object for a POST request. `data: {test:123}`

Comment: baao: I have tried that too, doesn't make any difference

Comment: if you guys bother to care, there's an answer with a solution below

Answer (score 0):

So this is how I solved it:

clientside:

```
function getData(number) {
  var teamId = number; // in data!!
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:80/getdata",
    crossDomain:true,
    dataType: "json",
    data:JSON.stringify(teamId)
  }).done(function ( data ) {
    var myJSON = JSON.stringify(data);
  }
```

server side:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
// Load the http module to create an http server.
var http = require('http');
const mysql = require('mysql');
app.post('/getdata', function(request, response) {
    var store = '';
    var query;
    var query2;
    // First you need to create a connection to the db
    const con = mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'db.host.net',
        user: 'dbuser',
        password: 'mypw',
        database: 'dbname',
    });
    request.on('data', function(data) {
        store += data;
        query = "regular db query";
        con.connect((err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Error connecting to Db');
                return;
            }
            console.log('Connection was established');
        });
        con.query(query, (err, rows) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            // handling query stuff

            query2 = "regular db query";

            // getting db query
            con.query(query2, (err, rows2) => {

                // handling query stuff

                if (err) throw err;

                myJSON = {
                    "var1": "data1",
                    "va2": "data2"
                }
                console.log("\nThe JSON resultset: " + JSON.stringify(myJSON));
                response.end(JSON.stringify(myJSON));
                con.end();
            });
        });
        console.log("DB connection ended");
    });
    request.on('end', function() {
        response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/json");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    });
}); app.listen(80);
```

Let me know if something is unclear or can be done better.